# How to evaluate this expected value integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, random-variables

I am trying to evaluate the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} xe^{\displaystyle\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xe^{\displaystyle\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}dx$$ 
which is the density of a standard normal random variable. I tried integration by parts, and got 
$$U = x, \qquad dU = dx, \qquad
 dV = e^{\displaystyle\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}dx \qquad V = e^{\displaystyle\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}$$

and so 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xe^{\displaystyle\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}dx = \Bigg[xe^{\displaystyle\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}\Bigg]_{-\infty}^{\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\displaystyle\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}dx$$

and get stuck there. It does not appear any simpler. How do I solve this?

Comment: The integrand $xe^{-x^2/2}$ is an odd function and hence the integral is zero.

Comment: I don't know what is an odd function. Can you elaborate on that a little more?

Comment: If $\; V = e^{\displaystyle\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}\;$ then $\;dV = e^{\displaystyle\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}\left(\dfrac{-x^{2}}{2}\right)'\,dx=\cdots$.

Comment: Instead of trying _integration by parts,_ find the _derivative_ of $-e^{-x^2/2}$ and admire it for a while. You might find that integration by parts is no longer needed; there are easier ways..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Instead of $U=x$, try $U=x^2$. Then $dU=2x$.